# A function that converts a string containing normal text to a string for URLs

Tags: php, string, url

For example:

`Mary has 50$ and 34€.`

If I paste this in the browser address bar I get redirected to Google and the URL contains:

`Mary+has+50$+and+34%E2%82%AC.`

Is there a PHP function that is able to do this?

I want to pass a string to a URL in curl and need to make it look like this, so it doesn't break anything

Comment: That string is URL encoded.  Have you looked at `urlencode (string $str)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to `urlencode()` the string:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: No problem. Please [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so we can close this case, and consider giving any other answers that helped an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)?

Answer (score 1):

urlencode might be what you're looking for: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

http_build_query is very useful as well depending on the data you are working with

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

string http_build_query ( mixed $query_data [, string $numeric_prefix [, string $arg_separator [, int $enc_type = PHP_QUERY_RFC1738 ]]] )
Generates a URL-encoded query string from the associative (or indexed) array provided.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$str = urlencode('Mary has 50$ and 34€.')
```

and to convert it back

```
$str = urldecode('Mary+has+50$+and+34%E2%82%AC.')
```